# Ruby on Rails selector title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selector

I follow the tutorial on railstutorials.org but it's a little bit older and I have a problem with the "have_selector"

I have to use this command :

```
it "doit avoir le bon titre" do
        get :home
        expect(response).to have_selector('title', 
                                           :text => " | Acceuil")
    end
```

But I have this error when I launch rspec spec/ :

```
1) PagesController GET home doit avoir le bon titre
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_selector('title',
       expected to find css "title" with text " | Acceuil" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the home.html.erb :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Simple App</h1>
    <p>
      Ceci est la page d'accueil de l'Application Exemple du
      <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my gemfile :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
ruby '2.2.0'
# Gem utile pour le sample d'exemple
gem 'gravatar_image_tag', '1.2.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.7'
gem 'rails_12factor'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.1.0'
  gem 'annotate', '2.6.5'
  gem 'faker', '1.4.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '3.1.0'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
  gem 'spork', '0.9.2'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.5.0'
end

group :production, :staging do
  gem "pg"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: I update the main question with the page

Answer (score 0):

My sense is you will be better served using Capybara's `has_title` or `have_title` methods. It seems more semantically meaningful to use `xxx_title` anyway since that's what your looking for.

`expect(page).to have_title('Some Content')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I try different combination with have_title but nothing works.. What is the correct fonction and how to use it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have not used Rspec in a bit (moved to Minitest late last year) but I believe `expect(page).to have_title('YOUR TEXT')` should work.

Comment: Bummer. When I run a spec I have that checks the page title (with the code snippet shown), it works. Note: have_title matches the entire title ... not just part of it. So, you would need to have `expect(page).to have_title("Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil")`

Comment: Here is the error now... :

Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_title("Simple App du Tutoriel Ruby on Rails | Accueil")
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PagesController::GETHome:0x00000006af3bf0>

Comment: My apologies ... I just now saw a comment in the OP where you're running this from a controller spec. I run tests like these from feature (i.e., integration) specs.

Comment: Ensure that you add `require 'capybara/rspec'` to your rails_helper.rb file or your spec_helper.rb file so that you have access to the Capybara matchers.

Comment: Anything new on this ? 
I'm having the same problem ...
A simple 

    expect(page).to have_content "success"

gives me a

NameError: undefined local variable or method `page' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::PagesController::GETMentions:0x00000006ffdc18>
./spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'